# React Native Firebase Get Document by Field Value (Wildcard) (doc path) Works in React but Not in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I will explain the issue below, but can say I think this line works for me in React but does not in React Native:

```
const postDocument = firebase.firestore().doc(`/posts/${id}`);
```

i then tried to write this and it returns some weird Promise:

```
const postDocument2 = firebase.firestore().collection('posts').where('id', '==', id);
```

What I want to do very clearly is to use this variable postDocument in the "hugPost" function for which ill provide code below. It works in React but not in React Native. Maybe variable postDocument isnt issue Im not sure.

```
hugPost = (id) => {
    const hugDocument = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('likes')
    .where('userHandle', '==', this.uid)
    .where('postId', '==', id)
    .limit(1); 

    const postDocument = firebase.firestore().doc(`/posts/${id}`);

    let postData;
   
//postDocument2
 postDocument
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        postData = doc.data();
        console.log("checking");
        postData.postId = doc.id;
        return hugDocument.get();
      } else {
        return ( 
          alert({
          error: 'Post not found'
          }));
      }
    })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.empty) {
          return firebase.firestore()
            .collection('likes')
            .add({
              postId: id,
              userHandle: this.uid
            })
            .then(() => {
              postData.likeCount++;
              return postDocument.update({ likeCount: postData.likeCount });
            })
            .then(() => {
              return (postData);
            });
        } else {
          return ( 
            alert({
            error: 'Post already liked'
            })); 
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(
          "Something went wrong, check your internet connection please",
          err
        );   
      });
  };
```

In React Native the function receives rightful id but doesnt work it goes straight to .catch saying my alert message "Something went wrong, check your internet connection please" and thworing [object object] error. Any help?

It recognizes NONE of these 3 as a doc i want which is inside collection posts and has field id (but it does recognize in React):

```
const postDocument2 = firebase.firestore().collection('posts').where('id', '==', id);
        
const postDocument = firebase.firestore().doc(`/posts/${id}`);

const postDocument3 = firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc('qRHqV8w6iyx4yHWg76tN');
```

Comment: `[object object]` is not very useful. How about if you `JSON.stringify(err)`?

Comment: I wrote that and it returned [object object] again..

Comment: There is no possible input to JSON.stringify that would return "[object object]". Maybe just console.log(err) and tell us what that is?

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.empty')

Comment: nevermind im close to solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it solved. Problem was that line const postDocument = firebase.firestore().doc(`/posts/${id}`);   only works if id is documents id and NOT field called id. Simply to a variable one needs to assign document id and use that in here.